# TPU terminology confusion

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

So I know how epochs, train steps, batch sizes and this kind of stuff are defined, but it is really hard to me to get my head wraped around the TPU terminology like train loops, iterations per loop and so on. I read [this](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting#iterations) but Im still confused.

Also how can I benchmark the time for iterations per loop for example.

Any explanation would help me a lot there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "train loop", I'm assuming it's the same meaning as ["training loop"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough#training_loop). The training loop is the one that iterates through each epoch in order to feed the model.

The iterations per loop is related to how Cloud TPU handles the training loop. In order to amortize the TPU launch cost, the model training step is wrapped in a tf.while_loop, such that one Session run actually runs many iterations for a single training loop.

Because of this, Cloud TPU runs a specified number of iterations of the training loop before returning to the host. Therefore, iterations_per_loop is how many iterations will run for one session.run call.

Comment: Thanks! So this means when training on CPU/GPU the CPU runs just one iteration for a session.run call?

Comment: As far as I can tell, on CPUs and GPUs each session.run call runs just one iteration, indeed.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers have described, `iterations_per_loop` is a tuning parameter that controls the amount of work done by the TPU before checking in with it again. A lower number lets you inspect results (and benchmark them) more often, and a higher number reduces the overhead due to synchronization.

This is no different from familiar network or file buffering techniques; changing its value affects performance, but not your final result. In contrast, ML hyperparameters like `num_epochs`, `train_steps`, or `train_batch_size` will change your result.

**EDIT:** Adding an illustration in pseudocode, below.  *Notionally,* the training loop functions like this:

```
def process_on_TPU(examples, train_batch_size, iterations_per_loop):
    # The TPU will run `iterations_per_loop` training iterations before returning to the host
    for i in range(0, iterations_per_loop):
        # on every iteration, the TPU will compute `train_batch_size` examples,
        # calculating the gradient from every example in the given batch
        compute(examples[i * train_batch_size : (i + 1) * train_batch_size])

# assume each entry in `example` is a single training example
for b in range(0, train_steps, train_batch_size * iterations_per_loop)
    process_on_TPU(examples[b:b + train_batch_size * iterations_per_loop],
                   train_batch_size,
                   iterations_per_loop)
```

From this, it might appear that `train_batch_size` and `iterations_per_loop` are simply two different ways of accomplishing the same thing.  However, this is not the case; `train_batch_size` affects the learning rate, since (at least in ResNet-50) the gradient is computed at each iteration from the average of the gradient of every example in the batch. Taking 50 steps per 50k examples will produce a different result from taking from 1k steps per 50k examples, since the latter case calculates the gradient much more often.

**EDIT 2:** Below is a way to visualize what's happening, with a racing metaphor.  Think of the TPU as running a race that has a distance of `train_steps` examples, and its stride lets it cover a batch of examples per step.  The race is on a track, which is shorter than the total race distance; the length of the lap is your total number of training examples, and every lap around the track is one epoch.  You can think of `iterations_per_loop` as being the point where the TPU can stop at a "water station" of sorts where the training is temporarily paused for a variety of tasks (benchmarking, checkpointing, other housekeeping).

[image: TPU ML Training Loop]

Comment: Hmm so what if trains_steps < train_batch_size * iterations_per_loop? Thanks!

Comment: From the following link: "the loop will exit before reaching the iterations_per_loop." https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/7884ed2f48e2bd8b03ad8f0416dac46770ddf63b/models/official/resnet/resnet_main.py#L125-L131

Comment: I mean in the lower loop has an increment of train_batch_size * iterations_per_loop. Shouldn't it be just itertions_per_loop?

Comment: No, the total number of examples passed to the TPU each time will be `train_batch_size * iterations_per_loop`. I added a cartoon to help illustrate the training loop.

Comment: For the cartoon! **`+1`**

Answer (score 1):

TPU literally means "Tensor Processing Unit", it's a hardware device used for computation in exactly the same way a GPU is used. The TPUs are effectively Google proprietary GPUs. There are technical differences under the hood of a GPU vs a TPU, mostly regarding speed and power consumption, and some issues of floating point precision, but you don't need to care about the details.

`iterations_per_loop` appears to be an effort to improve efficiency by loading the TPU with multiple training batches. There are often hardware bandwidth limitations when transferring large amounts of data from main memory to a GPU/TPU.

It appears that the code you reference is passing `iterations_per_loop` number of training batches to the TPU, then running `iterations_per_loop` number of training steps before pausing to do another data transfer from main memory to TPU memory.

I'm rather surprised to see that though, I would expect that asynchronous background data transfers would be possible by now.

*My only disclaimer* is that, while I'm proficient with Tensorflow, and have watched TPU evolution in papers and articles, I'm not directly experienced with the Google API or running on TPUs, so I'm inferring from what I read in the documentation you linked to.